# Find a word not proceeded by another word

Tags: python, regex

I am wondering how to write a regex pattern to find strings in which any word in a list is not proceeded by another word:

To give context, imagine two lists of words:

```
Parts = ['spout', 'handle', 'base']
Objects = ['jar', 'bottle']
```

Imagine the following strings

```
string = 'Jar with spout and base'
string2 = 'spout of jar'
string3 = 'handle of jar'
string4 = 'base of bottle with one handle' 
string5 = 'bottle base'
```

I want to write a rule so that if we have an expression like "spout of jar" or "handle of bottle" or "bottle base", I can output a statement like "object is fragment of jar, has part spout/base" into a dataframe but if we have an expression like "jar with spout", I can output an expression like "object is jug, has part spout".

Basically, I want to write a rule so that if any word in Parts is in the string, we write that the object is a fragment--unless the word is proceeded by 'with'.

So I wrote this, with negative lookbehind followed by .* followed by any word in Parts:

```
rf"(?!with)(.*)(?:{'|'.join(Part)})"
```

But this just does not seem to work: "jar with spout" will still match this pattern when I try it in Python.

So I am just not sure how to write a regex pattern to exclude any expression involving 'with' followed by any sequence of characters, followed by a word in Parts

Super grateful for any help that can be provided here!

Comment: I provided a PyPi regex solution, if you need help with integrating it in your Pandas solution, please update the question with the Pandas code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write such a pattern for PyPi `regex` library (install with `pip install regex`):

```
(?<!\bwith\b.*?)\b(?:spout|handle|base)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uRuKrz/1/). *Details*:

- `(?<!\bwith\b.*?)` - immediately to the left of the current location, there should be no whole word `with` and any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\b(?:spout|handle|base)\b` - a whole word `spout`, `handle`, or `base`.

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##RY8xU8UgEIT7/IrzNYCTSWPn6KS30d5YQLy8kOEBc5yjjvrbIxAcO469@3Y3fvIa/M2@20sMxEB4xo/uSRMnuIdnkWJ4Y9GDWLV/dVheRicUL92j2XBuW5umqgRmV7TEZP350B40wbvlFSoKMgYqoT/YEBao583hfy5bZTqoByN4hL8kzQ5anqiZkXz2rB2GOVyidShpOcnx7moyBTCZ4XpUk5Hj7Zf4FsMWrJe1rfrJ3yfVxZycJTibWC7WZaRs5CGhpnntobVTClS3778):

```
import regex
Parts = ['spout', 'handle', 'base']
Objects = ['jar', 'bottle']
strings = ['Jar with spout and base','spout of jar','handle of jar','base of bottle with one handle','bottle base']
pattern = regex.compile(rf"(?<!\bwith\b.*?)\b(?:{'|'.join(Parts)})\b")
print( list(filter(pattern.search, strings)) )
# => ['spout of jar', 'handle of jar', 'base of bottle with one handle', 'bottle base']
```

Comment: I have already downloaded regex. The reason I did not use your expression (?<!\bwith\b.*?) is because if I use negative lookbehind with wild card like you do, I get the error message "re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern"

Also, I used the expression (?:{'|'.join(Part)})" because I want to be able to add to my list of words in Part without having to add it to every line using any of those words

Comment: @kylemaxim Yes, you need to use a separate method with `.apply`. The regex requires `regex` library and not the `re`, so that `re.error` could not be thrown. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052973/find-a-word-not-proceeded-by-another-word/64053261?noredirect=1#comment113267436_64052973). If you need further help, help us help you.

Comment: Thank you! This is very interesting, when I used re.compile and then tried the original pattern that I wrote, it worked! Is the issue here that I wasn't using compile() ?

Comment: @kylemaxim No, your original pattern does not work. It matches  a location not immediately followed with `with` string, then matches any text and then one of your parts.

Comment: Apply with pandas also worked excellently, thank you!